# .rsplit() function usage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame named "team". it includes mixed names. I want to take only team names which is exists at the end of the each row. the code is accurate but can you explain how this `.rspilt` function works?

[image]

```
nba_df["team_only"] = nba_df.team.apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(None, 1)[-1])
```

Comment: This is just the `split()` method, but it simply starts from the right instead of the left

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
nba_df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['aa AA', 'bb BB', 'cc CC']})
nba_df['team_only'] = nba_df.team.apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])

print(nba_df)
```

Alternative:

```
nba_df['team_only'] = [team.split()[-1] for team in nba_df.team]

print(nba_df)
```

Output:

```
    team team_only
0  aa AA        AA
1  bb BB        BB
2  cc CC        CC
```